# Running functions with COM objects in parallel

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I have four sites which I have to check specific HTML for every so often and I'd like to automate this. I've tried to use `Invoke-WebRequest` but I couldn't figure out how to step through the pages since a lot of AJAX is being used. This is why I use two IE COM objects. With the COM objects I can easily step through and search for the correct HTML on each page.

The problem is that the checks run sequentially:

```
#Define functions
site1 { }
site2 { }
etc..
#run functions
$result = site1 #returns bool
$result = site2 #returns bool
etc..
```

I'd like to have the site checks run at the same time but I have been unable to do so with either `Start-Job` or a workflow.

I don't think I have figured out the syntax for either option as the `Visible` property from the IE COM object never triggers:

```
$url = "somesite.com"
$site = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application
$site.Silent = $true
$site.Navigate($url)
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep -m 500} 
$site.Visible = $true
```

What is the proper way to have these site checks run at the same time and also have them be visible?

Comment: I think the only possible reason is that the site never loads. Try to see what's happening by making the window visible before the sleep loop. As for the proper method, I don't see why accessing them directly as `$ie1`, `$ie2` etc should be a problem.

Comment: If I run the code in normal sequential order I can access the com object normally. In a workflow such as:
workflow{
  function site1 { }
  site1 #<- doesn't write-host or return visible = true
}

Comment: I changed my script a bit and it seem's to be visible now but at some point it waits for user input with read-host but quickly passes over it. Is there any reason you know of why this read-host isn't waited for?

Comment: There is no `Read-Host` in the code you posted. Please edit your question and show your actual code, not something you fabricated or typed from memory.